# What is the difference between 'legumes' and 'vegetais'?

Tags: português-europeu, vocabulário

Google tells me that both 'legumes' and 'vegetais' mean 'vegetables'.

Can anyone give me a little more detail on their meanings and the right contexts to use them in?

Comment: Hello Kriss, this is a very good question! I edited your question to try to improve it; I changed the title and the content a bit. If you prefer the previous version, you can always check the [revision history for your question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/7671/revisions) and rollback :) to your original version.

Comment: You can say "animais e vegetais" (biology) or "carnes e legumes" (food). It gets a little weird if you mix them up (e.g. animais e legumes)

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr — "*vegetal*" is a vegetable; "*legume*" is a vegetable from horticulture.

---

## "*Vegetal*"

"*Vegetal*" means vegetable.
It is the same word as in English.

This word has a precise definition, and its common use matches the scientific definition.

Trees, shrubs, grasses, they are all vegetables.

The Priberam dictionary [defines it as](https://dicionario.priberam.org/vegetal):

> ve·ge·tal
>
> adjectivo de dois géneros
>
> 1. Relativo às plantas.
>
> substantivo masculino
>
> 2. **Árvore; planta.** [Tree; plant]
> 3. Terra proveniente das decomposições vegetais. = HÚMUS

"vegetal", in *Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa* [online], 2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/vegetal [visited in 09-04-2020].

## "*Legume*"

"*Legume*" is a *common word* for an horticulture produce.

It's a fuzzy word with a more fluid meaning.
It's the name in the supermarket for "fruits and vegetables": "frutas e legumes".

The root of the word "*legume*" is the same word as the root for the English word "legume" (pt: *leguminosa*).

The Priberam dictionary [defines it as](https://dicionario.priberam.org/legume):

> le·gu·me
>   substantivo masculino
>
> 1. Grão das plantas faseoláceas.
> 2. [Botânica]  Planta hortense que dá vagem.
> 3. Produto da horticultura.
> 4. Hortaliça.

"legume", in *Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa* [online], 2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/legume [visited 09-04-2020].

I would translate that as:

> 1. Grain from the [Fabaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabaceae) family. ("Phaseollaceae"? Just... yeah, ignore that.)
> 2. [Botanic] Horticultural plant that yields pods.
> 3. Horticulture produce.
> 4. Edible greenery produce from horticulture.

Kale, broad-beans, carrots, tomato, cucumber, bell-pepper, are "*legumes*": horticulture products.

Comment: Tangent: the tomato and the cucumber are *legumes* (vegetables), not *frutas* (fruits)... but they're *frutos*. *Fruta* is a common word defined by daily usage, and *fruto* is a scientific word with a strict definition; so a melon is both *fruto* and *fruta*; but pumpkin is *fruto* and not *fruta* but *legume*.

Comment: In my experience, and also according to Wikipedia and dictionaries, lemon is a fruit ("*fruta*"), also "*fruta*" is simply an edible "*fruto*" according to, e.g., [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/fruta).

Comment: I can agree to put the lemon next to the other citrus, which are fruits; but I don't find any dictionary evidence that is is *fruta*. I will replace it with pumpkin or cucumber, thank you for pointing out the weak example.

Comment: «also "*fruta*" is simply an edible "*fruto*"» With that I don't agree. A lot of "*legumes*" are edible fruit, and they're not considered "fruta"; doesn't that show that the definition is not strict? Pumpkin, cucumber, tomato, they're edible fruits but not *fruta*, don't you agree?... this is a very interesting theme of discussion. : )

Comment: I think this could help. In common talk about food, *legumes* means ’vegetables’ (except perhaps that I (we?) do not think of potatoes as a legume), and that's basically the only word we used do use in Portugal. But of late we've come to use the word *vegetais* in place of *legumes* in sentences like, "temos de comer mais vegetais", "comer vegetais é bom para a saúde", etc. I think that's inlfuence of the English language. But *frutas e legumes* is such a stock phrase that *legumes* hasn't ceded *vegetais* an inch  in there.

Comment: I agree, ANeves, the **culinary** fruit (*fruta*), being an everyday concept, is more vaguely defined than the **botanical** fruit (*fruto*). Probably even the dictionary means "some *frutos comestíveis*" rather than "any *frutos comestíveis*" when it defines *fruta* simply as "*frutos comestíveis*". It's indeed an interesting discussion: as culinary is part of culture, different groups are bound to classify differently, or even follow totally unrelated classifications.

Comment: @Jacinto I don't think I have seen this use of *vegetais* in pt-br, but I can very well imagine it's happening, for the reason you gave. As for potatoes, I'd speculate some people don't quite classify it as a *legume*, because the latter is associated with healthy foods, while potatoes are seen more as a rich source of carbs. :-)

Comment: ANeves e @Jacinto, I've just posted and answered a very similar question [here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/7674/2764). Since it asks about *verduras* e *frutas* too, I think it's not a duplicate, but if the consensus would be otherwise, I could translate the answer and post it here instead. I might then have to translate the long quote from Wikipedia too, since I didn't find an English equivalent as good as the entry in Portuguese.

Comment: @stafusa, *vegetais* in this sense is still less common than *legumes*, but I have heard it. As for potatoes it's basically that, but in the farming community I grew up in we saw it from a different angle. My parents generation, before I was born, often wished they had more to eat. So potatoes belonged with bread, rice, pasta, beans -- the energetic basis of a meal, to keep you going, that gives "sustância". *Legumes* are good, but fill you up only for a while.

Comment: My view of potatoes is similar to the one @Jacinto shows in this last comment. A stereotypical meal has a chunk of carbs (potatoes/rice/pasta), then some protein (meat/fish/eggs), then some vegetables; the potatoes get categorized outside of vegetables, even though they're technically not much different from carrots or turnips. :)

Comment: @stafusa, I don't think it's a duplicate. And I would be glad to see more responses here; go ahead and post one! :) For a languages site, even if the content itself is the same, in my opinion a different presentation is enough to justify a new answer - and I think this brings very good value. Maybe one answer has a long and nitpicky explanation and another one has a clear-cut simple and short explanation... these will serve different users; or they use different styles or writing; or they focus on different cultures; or... :)