# Qual é a diferença entre verdura, legume e fruta?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

No sentido cotidiano, culinário (em oposição ao da botânica) das palavras, qual é a diferença entre verdura e legume? E quando um fruto é chamado fruta, e quando é chamado legume?

Os dicionários parecem ser de pouca ajuda para fazer essa diferenciação:

- Priberam:

> **verdura** - Hortaliça
>   **legume** - Produto da horticultura. Hortaliça.
>   **hortaliça** - Nome genérico das plantas herbáceas comestíveis de que se aproveita a raiz, o caule, a folha ou o fruto (excepção feita dos legumes).
>   **fruta** - Fruto comestível.

- Aulete:

> **verdura** - Planta comestível, ger. cultivada em hortas; HORTALIÇA
>   **legume** - Ver hortaliça.
>   **hortaliça** - Denominação genérica de plantas cultivadas em horta para alimentação humana; ERVA; VERDURA
>   **fruta** - Nome comum a todos os frutos, pseudofrutos e infrutescências comestíveis

Comment: No sentido cotidiano brasileiro, verdura são as folhas verdes, fruta é algo "doce" que você comeria de sobremesa. Tudo o que sobra, exceto arroz e feijão, é chamado de legume.

Comment: Eu geralmente digo "fruta" para tudo, porquanto eu nunca soube diferenciar os termos. Até hoje ninguém reclamou; mas se falo *vegetal* para algo que não se geralmente considera vegetal, ouço coisa.

Comment: @Schilive No plural, imagino que possa funcionar - mas se você oferecer uma fruta para alguém e entregar uma berinjela acho que não será bem recebido. :-D

Comment: As abóboras e as cenouras são legumee, mas não são verduras. Verdura: que contém a cor verde.

Answer (score 4):

Sem nenhuma referência, meu **conhecimento popular** é bem simples e fácil de lembrar:

**Consideramos verduras, os caules, folhas e flores comestíveis**: alface, agrião, espinafre, rúcula, bertalha, repolho, couve-flor, brócoli, brócoli americano, aipo, aspargos, palmito, vagem, etc.

**Fruta é todo vegetal que tem caroço ou semente cuja função é a reprodução**: abóbora, mamão, tomate, laranja, pera, maçã, uva, abacate, etc.  Bananas têm sementes embora a reprodução seja feita por estaca.

**legumes são as frutas pouco doces, tubérculos, raízes e bulbos** que fazem parte do nosso cardápio de refeições: aipim, inhame, cenoura, batatas diversas, abóbora, tomate, pepino, berinjela, alho, cebola, abacate (em algumas culturas).

**Tudo isso é "cultura popular", a forma como o povo classifica**.  Não adianta querer discutir com o feirante que abóbora e tomate são frutos, que a couve-flor é uma flor, e que a cenoura é uma raíz.

**Classificações científicas já ficam no campo da botânica**, e não no uso dessas palavras na língua portuguesa.

Comment: Bem claro; gosto. Mas estou a entender corretamente que "fruta" é mutuamente exclusivo com "legumes"? Que normalmente, cada vegetal é posto em apenas uma dessas 3 categorias, mesmo que pudesse caber (menos bem, talvez) numa das outras?

Comment: @ANeves    Popularmente, a abóbora e o tomate são encontrados na seção de legumes dos super-mercados.  O abacate é junto com a frutas.  No entanto, abóbora e tomate têm sementes para reprodução e, em tese, são frutas.  O abacate, em países como o México, é uma fruta utilizada em receitas de saladas e pratos salgados.  Não sei como os mexicanos o classificam popularmente.  No Brasil ainda é consumido principalmente como fruta.

Comment: Ótima a inclusão de exemplos. Só palmito que, junto com a cebola, penso que consideraria um legume.

Comment: @stafusa   Cebola foi citada em legumes.

Comment: Eu sei, acho que não fui claro - o que quis dizer é que colocaria o palmito junto com ela, entre os legumes.

Comment: @stafusa Bem, o palmito é um caule, assim como o alho-poró e o aipo. Ele é branco porque a casca foi retirada.

Comment: abóbora é curcubita e é uma fruta. Mas popularmente, é legume.

Answer (score 3):

Termos do cotidiano, especialmente quando usados para classificações, raramente admitem definições rigorosas como as que se usam nas ciências.

Por exemplo, é comum se falar em "pessoas e animais", apesar de pessoas, biologicamente, também serem animais. Nesse sentido, é importante deixar claro o contexto em que os termos estão sendo usados - aqui, o cotidiano/culinário, em oposição ao biológico/botânico.

O (curto) verbete da Wikipedia em português esclarece muito bem essa situação e vale a leitura (grifo meu):

### [Hortaliça](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hortali%C3%A7a):

> Dentre as categorias de plantas alimentícias, ou comestíveis, os conceitos são bastante abrangentes e não excludentes.
>
> Não são geralmente consideradas hortaliças as frutas, os frutos secos, as especiarias, os grãos, as batatas e algumas raízes tuberosas, como a mandioca. No entanto, do ponto de vista nutricional, todos estes produtos, com exceção das frutos doces, podem ser consideradas hortaliças.
>
> Em botânica, os termos "fruto" e "legume" têm significados bem definidos, mas "hortaliça" e "verdura" não. Já em agronomia, em culinária e em linguagem popular, as definições podem variar, e o uso destes termos é muitas vezes indiscriminado. Alguns separam as plantas (ou suas partes) consumidas em **frutas (vegetais doces)** e **hortaliças (vegetais não-doces)** e, por sua vez, as hortaliças são divididas em **verduras (consumidas cruas)** e **legumes (consumidos após cozimento)**. Outros separam as hortaliças com base no tipo de órgão: **verduras seriam as folhas e flores comestíveis**, e **legumes seriam os frutos (no sentido botânico) não-doces, os caules e os órgãos subterrâneos** (raízes, tubérculos e bulbos) **comestíveis**.
>
> O termo legume, em botânica, serve para designar um tipo de fruto (no sentido botânico), também chamado vagem e as sementes que contêm, como os feijões.
>
> Usualmente, as verduras incluem as folhas (por exemplo, da alface), caules (espargo) e raizes de diversas plantas, como a cenoura. Mas o termo pode também incluir frutos não-doces, como as vagens verdes (por exemplo, do feijão) ou as suas sementes (como as das favas), o pepino, os diferentes tipos de abóboras, tomates, abacates e pimentas.
>
> Por extensão, consideram-se por vezes como hortaliças algumas sementes já maduras (secas), como as ervilhas e feijões, que se cozinham depois de ensopadas em água para facilitar a cozedura.
>
> Diante dessa diversidade de conceitos, uma alternativa é o uso do termo generalista "planta comestível".

**Update**: Reiterando a busca sobre o assunto, encontram-se muitas fontes contraditórias na rede — provavelmente variações regionais e de contexto, além de interpretações pessoais. Há até quem [afirme](https://www.tuasaude.com/diferenca-entre-legumes-e-verduras/) que frutas são uma categoria de legumes. Acho que fico com o encerramento de uma [matéria](https://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/portuguese/amesa/2011/04/verdura-ou-legume.html) da BBC Brasil a respeito:

> Resumindo: vou continuar a ter as dúvidas que levantei no início deste post. Na boa: seria tudo mais fácil se fizéssemos que nem os ingleses, chamássemos todos eles de vegetais, e ponto.

Comment: Em pt-PT, "legume-vagem" é "leguminosa". No Brasil não? O Aulete [diz](http://www.aulete.com.br/leguminosa) que o "fruto [da leguminosa] é o legume". Hmm... será que isto é também verdade em pt-PT?

Comment: @ANeves Não lembro de ver em pt-BR "leguminosa" ser usado no dia a dia, só no sentido da botânica - que é o que consta no verbete do Aulete que você linkou; aliás, não encontrei "legume-vagem" nem no Priberam, nem na Infopédia.

Comment: (Quando escrevi "legume-vagem", queria significar "legume (na definição de vagem)", por oposição a "legume (na definição de planta)". O *-vagem* era... uma espécie de qualificador; mas não uma parte de uma palavra realmente existente.)

Comment: @ANeves (－‸ლ)  (facepalm).